# Updating multiple rows with a conditional where clause in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to update multiple rows in a single query as I have many rows to update at once. In my query, there is a where clause that applies only to certain rows.

For example, I've the following query:

```
update mytable as m set
    column_a = c.column_a,
    column_b = c.column_b
from (values
    (1, 12, 6, TRUE),
    (2, 1, 45, FALSE),
    (3, 56, 3, TRUE)
) as c(id, column_a, column_b, additional_condition)
where c.id = m.id
     and CASE c.additional_condition when TRUE m.status != ALL(array['active', 'inactive']) end;
```

The last line in the `where` clause (`m.status != ALL(array['active', 'inactive'])`) should only be applied to rows which has `TRUE` in the value of `c.additional_condition`. Otherwise, the condition should not be applied.

Is it possible to achieve this in Postgres?

Comment: *The last line in the where clause (m.status = 'active') ...* there is no `m.status = 'active'` but `m.status != ALL(array['active', 'inactive'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

```
and CASE  
  when c.additional_condition THEN m.status != ALL(array['active', 'inactive']) 
  else TRUE
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you want is:

```
where c.id = m.id and
      ( (not c.additional_condition) and orm.status = 'active' )
```

You can use `in` or arrays for multiple values:

```
where c.id = m.id and
      ( (not c.additional_condition) and orm.status not in ( 'active', 'inacctive') )
```

I don't see a particular value to use arrays, unless you are passing a value in as an array.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("`. I've having something that looks like this:
`where... and
      ( (not c.additional_condition) (m."status") != ALL(array['active', 'inactive']) )`